# How can a branch be both X commits ahead and Y commits behind?

Tags: git, github

I was checking some of the projects in github and in one of them I noticed this:

`This branch is 287 commits ahead, 361 commits behind X:Master`

How exactly is this possible ?

Answer (score 6):

Just like that:

```
       o ----- ... 285 commits ... -- o     <-- master
      /
o -- o -- o -- ... 359 commits ... -- o     <-- X/master
```

You created 287 commits on branch `master` in your local repository. These commits are not accessible from `X/master`. This is why `master` is *"287 commits ahead `X/master`"*.

In the same time, other developers created 361 new commits on `X/master`. Since the local `master` and `X/master` diverged, these 361 commits are not accessible from `master` and that's why `master` is *"361 commits behind `X/master`"*.

This is a normal situation in a versioning control system. You can synchronize your `master` branch with `X/master` in two ways:

1. **merge**

   Run:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge X/master
   ```

   This creates a new commit that contains all the changes from both `master` and `X/master` and has two parents: the current tips of the `master` and `X/master` branches.

   If it succeeds, the graph looks like this:

   ```
                                      +--- old "master"  
                                      v
          o -- ... 285 commits ... -- o -- o   <-- master (the merge commit)
         /                                /
   o -- o -- o -- ... 359 commits ... -- o     <-- X/master
   ```
2. **rebase**

   Run:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git rebase X/master
   ```

   This moves all the commits that are on `master` but not on `X/master` (the 287 commits that are "ahead") on the `X/master` branch, after the commits 361 that are on `X/master` and are not accesible from `master`.

   If it succeeds, the graph will look like this:

   ```
        +--- old split point
        v
   o -- o - ... 360 commits ... - o - ... 286 commits ... - o   <-- master
                                  ^
                                  +---- X/master
   ```

Comment: Though in fact, with that many different commits, it seems fairly likely that someone else already did a rebase.  OP should note that rebase works by *copying* commits. If you and they had 287 shared commits and they had 74 unshared new commits, and "they" rebased their 287 to new copies, they'd suddenly have 287 + 74 = 361 commits you don't, and you'd have 361 - 74 = 287 original (pre-copying) commits they don't.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple:

- at time X the branch was created from master
- changes were made to the branch and pushed to the server
- changes were made to the master and pushed to the server

After this the branch is ahead master by its changes and behind it by the changes that have been pushed to master. They need rebase or merge to be combined.